# How to create a function for a button that is dynamically added to the website? Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi so I'm creating this Image Upload feature but **I'm stuck with the logic of creating a function for the dynamically added call to action buttons**. So I have this drag and drop upload image, and when you drop the image in the drop-area it'll automatically display a preview of the image and that preview image has a button below in it, a **Remove Button**

```js
const previewImage = function(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => {        
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'preview-image-result';
    div.innerHTML = `
      <img src="${reader.result}">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <span class="remove-image-button" onclick="removeImage()">Remove Image</span>
      </div>
    `;
  }
  document.getElementById('preview-image-container').prepend(div);
}
```

I tried to add a `onclick=removeImage()` in the `<span>` but it returns error and says `(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: removeImage is not defined` I assume that since the `<span>Remove Image</span>` is dynamically added to the site it is not detecting the `removeImage()` method I created. Anyone can help me on what method to use in this kind of workflow or am I missing something? using **Vanilla Javascript**

```js
const removeImage = function() {
 // remove image
}
```

Comment: `removeImage` would have to exist in global scope for this to work. The error indicates that it doesn't. But `this.remove()` won't work because `this` won't refer to the element the function is bound to.

Comment: *"I assume that since the <span>Remove Image</span> is dynamically added to the site it is not detecting the removeImage() method I created."* - That doesn't sound right.  Can you take a few moments to create a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: If `removeImage` function is not declared in the global context, then it cannot be called in this way. Declare this function globally, for example, through `window.removeImage = function () { ... }`. Although a better idea would be to use the insertion of new elements through the manipulation of DOM, and not the target insertion of HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, thanks for pointing it out on the comments. The `removeImage()` is placed inside of the **jQuery(document).ready(function () {
})** I change the placement of the `removeImage()` outside of the
**jQuery(document).ready(function () {})** and It works!

```
const removeImage = function() {
  // remove image
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
const previewImage = function(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => {        
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'preview-image-result';
    div.innerHTML = `
      <img src="${reader.result}">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <span class="remove-image-button" onclick="removeImage()">Remove Image</span>
      </div>
    `;
  }
  document.getElementById('preview-image-container').prepend(div);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

An event listener on the document will do:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  if(event.target.classList.contains("remove-image-button"){
    event.target.closest(".preview-image-result").remove();
  }
})
```

So if any click on the document occurs **and** the clicked element has the `remove-image-button` class, its `preview-image-result` parent will be removed.

Adding an event listener to the document and checking for specific condition of the clicked element is also called *event delegation*.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if the dynamic part of OP code actually works so in the example below the `img` has been added dynamically. The event handler `removeImg(e)` has been bound to an ancestor element `<section>`. Through event delegation, any button of any amount can be controlled as long as it's within the `<section>`. The event handler has been designed only to react to any click on `.btn` and nothing else.

```js
const sec = document.querySelector('section');
const previewImage = () => {
  let img = `
    <figure class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hZj77BZ/lena01.jpg" width='150'><figcaption><button class="btn">Remove Image</button></figcaption></figure>
    `;
  sec.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', img);
}

previewImage();

const removeImg = e => {
  const btn = e.target;
  if (btn.matches('.btn')) {
    let imgFrame = btn.closest('figure');
    imgFrame.remove();
  }
};

sec.onclick = removeImg;
```

```html
<section></section>
```